# Switch in Power BI Table Visual in combination with Division is showing empty value while the same measure works for Card Visual

Tags: powerbi, finance, calculation

While Creating a Balance Sheet in Power BI im using a Switch in a Measure to load the corresponding Numbers to the position in the Report. At the moment it shows an empty value see 1. I try to get it to look like see 2:

[image]

The Switch:

```
Actual PY = SWITCH(
SELECTEDVALUE(financialStatementStructure[accountId]),
100, FORMAT([100], "#,##0"),
1, FORMAT([currentAssetsInPercent], "0.0%"),
200, FORMAT([200], "#,##0"),
300, FORMAT([300], "#,##0"),
400, FORMAT([400], "#,##0"),
500, FORMAT([500], "#,##0"),
600, FORMAT([600], "#,##0"),
700, FORMAT([700], "#,##0"),
800, FORMAT([800], "#,##0"),
900, FORMAT([900], "#,##0")
)
```

Measure [currentAssetsInPercent]:

```
currentAssetsInPercent = DIVIDE([100], [400], 0)
```

Connection between the tables:

[image]

Slicers for the Table:

```
unitNumber
year
quarter
```

Measure [100]:

```
100 = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('combinedAccountValue'[value]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('date'),
        'date'[yearQuarter] = (SELECTEDVALUE('date'[yearQuarter]) -10)
    ),
    'combinedAccountValue'[accountId] = 100,
    'combinedAccountValue'[reportTypeId] = 1
)
```

Measure [400] looks similar to this. Those measures involve the Filter for reportTypeId. This should give a uniq row to lookup in the accountValue table.

This works fine for the Card Visual but not for the Table. What do i miss out here? :S

*This is just an example as i cannot show the actual balance sheet. Therefore i can also not upload the PBI-File*

Comment: it appears your filter context is impacting the measure. I would debug and see what the selected value of year quarter and the selected value of account id evaluate to in your table visual. Perhaps there is no filter context on the table itself.

Comment: The values for year 2022, quarter 4 and unit_number 1000 are correct. Only difference i can find with the Performance Analyzer is: "100", IGNORE('AccountValue'[100]) for the card and there is no IGNORE for the Table. Neither do i know what this means nor how to change it :D

Comment: Does the filter from the first measure lose its validity when it is referenced in another measure?  I can even create another empty table and just add the 3 measures and get the right numbers. Seems to be the Switch Function doesn't it? :S